# line chart with xtics month and year

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I've succeeded build a line chart using Gnuplot.

Now I am trying to put date on my x axis. Here is my data:

```
    service1    service2    service3
12/28/2014  0   0   0
11/24/2014  1   2   0
10/06/2014  5   4   1
08/30/2014  10  6   0
03/13/2014  15  8   0
```

And this is my plot file before I add date format:

```
set term pos eps font 20
set output 'line.eps'

    plot "data.dat" using 2  smooth cumulative t 's1' with lines, \
         "data.dat" using 3  smooth cumulative t 's2' with lines, \
         "data.dat" using 4  smooth cumulative t 's3' with lines
```

I add date format to my plot, like this:

```
set term pos eps font 20
set output 'line.eps'

set xdata time
set timefmt "%m/%d/%y"
set xrange ["01/01/2009":"12/01/2014"]

plot "data.dat" using 2  smooth cumulative t 's1' with lines, \
     "data.dat" using 3  smooth cumulative t 's2' with lines, \
     "data.dat" using 4  smooth cumulative t 's3' with lines
```

and the error is:

```
"plot.plt", line 10: Need full using spec for x time data
```

after that I tried to add change the plot script, like this:

```
plot "data.dat" using 1:2  smooth cumulative t 's1' with lines, \
     "data.dat" using 1:3  smooth cumulative t 's2' with lines, \
     "data.dat" using 1:4  smooth cumulative t 's3' with lines
```

and gave me error:

```
    service1    service2    service3
data.dat:1:"plot.plt", line 10: illegal month
```

It seems there are something different with the previous graph. Could someone tell me, how to solve this problem? My expectation is shown a graph as this image below but using month format in x axis.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you, that in the first line of your file `data.dat`, which contains `service1 service2 service3`, gnuplot encountered an illegal month...

You can either

- Remove the first line
- Comment the first line
- Skip the first line with `every ::1`

Another issue: A four-digit year is specified with `%Y`. The following works fine here:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m/%d/%Y"
set format x "%m/%Y"
set xrange ["01/01/2009":"12/01/2014"]

plot "data.dat" using 1:2 every ::1 smooth cumulative t 's1' with lines, \
     "data.dat" using 1:3 every ::1 smooth cumulative t 's2' with lines, \
     "data.dat" using 1:4 every ::1 smooth cumulative t 's3' with lines
```

Comment: Delightful! Hi @christoph. It's work for me. Since the range are 6 years. the x axis are cannot be read. is it possible to sorter the range? maybe every 3 months or 6 months?

Comment: You can set the frequency of the xtics. The value must be given in seconds, so you can try to use `set xtics 3*30*24*60*60`. I'm not sure, how gnuplot internally deals with the different number of days per month.